# Field calculator uses wrong fields when working with joined data

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-joins, sqlite

I am having an issue in qgis table joins.
i have a joined a csv file to a sqlite database and common id is used for join.
the join is displays correctly in  attribute table.

the attributes in sqlite file is **id** and the csv file has **id, building, surveyorid, surveydate**. I want to add the **surveydate** information to the sqlite data permanently.

In the field calculator. i created a new field **survey_date**.

the expression field is **"surveydate"** (field from csv file), the output preview displays the result correctly.

The problem is on clicking ok, the new field(**survey_date**) gets populated with values of **surveyorid**. I tried other cases and each time, the new field gets populated with values from the field that is before the field in expression, i.e. if i try with surveyorid, i get the building values.

Comment: I've run into a bug where field calculations use the wrong field if some fields are turned off. Are all fields turned on in the joined layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug (see http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9628 - apparently fixed in 2.2.)

Possible workaround:
I have experienced that when using fields from joined tables (I have tested dbf and csv), the field calculator messes things up when I choose "Create new field".  If I change to "Update existing field", things seem to work.